# Align frame with surrounding text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings

In the following minimal working example, the text of the listing is aligned with the surrounding text, thus the border on the left protrudes into the margin.
I prefer to have the frame align with the surrounding text and do not mind the code to be indented as a result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=l}
\begin{document}
\noindent
test
\begin{lstlisting}
code
\end{lstlisting}
More text
\end{document}
```

I would provide an attempt which you guys can fix, but I have no clue how to tackle this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the left margin (option `xleftmargin`) by the values of options `framesep` + `framerule`. The default of these options can be found in the manual, “4.3.10 Frames”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=l,xleftmargin=3.4pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent
test
\begin{lstlisting}
code
\end{lstlisting}
More text
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also use a right frame rule, there you can use option `xrightmargin` analogous.